# Javascript hash (node.js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, hash

I am having trouble with accessing a key in a hash (I am programming in Node.js if that matters).

I have a callback when return a status and a reply like this:

```
client.metadata(folder, options, function(status, reply){
  //console.log(reply)
  console.log(reply)
  console.log("New hash: " + reply['hash']);
});
```

The problem is, reply['hash'] returns undefined. even reply.hash is undefined. How can I access the hash key in reply?

I logged reply and it is:

```
{
  "hash": "e533d2c19d236d0d4f84e2a9666659e1",
  "revision": 802,
  "rev": "32203a97cb5",
  "thumb_exists": false,
  "bytes": 0,
  "modified": "Wed, 04 Jan 2012 02:39:18 +0000",
  "path": "/foo",
  "is_dir": true,
  "icon": "folder",
  "root": "dropbox",
  "contents": [],
  "size": "0 bytes"
}
```

but when i access hash in reply like in above example, it's:

> New hash: undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be possible that the reply is a string type, and you need to convert it from JSON with a `JSON.parse(reply)`...

Check out the type of the reply with `console.log(typeof reply)` and see what it say

Comment: Thanks that was it. it was a string. After parsing it, it works!